# extern c template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, extern-c

I want to write a templated function and explicitly instantiate it inside extern "C" block to avoid code duplication.

Here is example of what I mean:

```
template<typename T> // my templated function
T f(T val){
    return val;
}

extern "C"{
   int f_int(int val) = f<int>; // this does not compile, but this is what I want to achieve
}
```

Comment: this wouldnt work also outside of `extern "C"`. Please include the compiler error message in the question

Comment: `int f_int(int val) {return f<int>(val);}`

Comment: You can't define functions like you do variables. `int f(int) { return 0; } int g(int) = f;` wouldn't work either (and the `extern "C"` is irrelevant to the problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int f_int(int val) = f<int>;` is not valid(legal) C++ syntax.  The correct syntax to instantiate the function template and return the result of calling that instantiated function with `val` as argument would look something like:

```
template<typename T> // my templated function
T f(T val){
    return val;
}

extern "C"{
   int f_int(int val) {return f<int>(val);} // this does not compile, but this is what I want to achieve
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hGjMr5PPd)